# Dividing error in java language

Tags: java

I have a simple java program that does not operate the way that I think it should.

```
public class Divisor
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int answer = 5 / 2;
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Why is this not printing out 2.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 / 2 is integer division (you're even storing it in an integer variable), if you want it to be 2.5, you need to use floating point division:

```
double answer = 5.0 / 2.0;
```

Integer division is always going to be equal to normal mathematical division rounded down to the nearest integer.

Comment: No need to have every operand double, just one of them is fine (`5.0/2 = 5/2.0 = 2.5`)

Comment: @BackSlash So? What you're talking about is still compiling to *the exact same thing*. The only difference is you're making the compiler convert an integer to a floating point number so that it can do proper floating point division. You're just being lazy for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2):

Java has integer division which says: **integer divided by integer results in integer**. `2.5` cannot be represented with integer so the result is floored to `2.0`. Moreover, you store the result in integer.

If you need floating point division you can cast one of operands to double and change `answer` type to `double` as well. You use literal values here, so changing `5` to `5.` makes this literal value `double`.

In the end the following should work for you:

```
double answer = 5. / 2;
```

Note, you don't even need a zero sign after a dot symbol!